# Why are we able to ignore the henries, Hz, farads, siemens and ohms when calculating the characteristic impedance of a transmission line?

Tags: characteristic-impedance, units

I have seen calculations, and every time we just take the coefficents of these values and end up calculating a simple complex number. The units all equate to various exponents of area, second, metre and kg, but they do NOT cancel out.

Also as we have a root, which complex number is the actual answer, is it dependent on context?

$$=\sqrt{\frac{R + 2\pi f L j}{G + 2\pi f C j}}$$

Comment: Whatever you've seen in calculations is wrong then. The unit of characteristic impedance is Ω. So, there's isn't really anything to answer here – complex impedance very much has a unit, and it as you say, it doesn't cancel out.

Comment: However, this tells me that whatever introduction you're reading about transmission line theory isn't really good – it should clearly introduce how you happen to end up with something that has the same unit as a resistance when relating electric fields and magnetic fields.

Comment: now you even have a formula in your question that demonstrates the unit is the same as that of a resistance. So, the claim in your first sentence is plain wrong.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't see how that equates to ohms?

Comment: @ocrdu, you reversed my edit removing the original erroneous capitalisation of the SI units, henries, farads, siemens and ohms. The SI standard is, "*Units: The names of all units start with a lower case letter except, of course, at the beginning of the sentence. There is one exception: in "degree Celsius" (symbol °C) the unit "degree" is lower case but the modifier "Celsius" is capitalized.*" (Although note that the SI unit of temperature is 'K'/kelvin.) See https://www.nist.gov/pml/weights-and-measures/writing-si-metric-system-units. Can you undo your edit?

Comment: @Transistor: sorry about that, and done. How about Hz? Leave as-is or put "herz"?

Comment: 'Hz' or hertz is correct so I don't mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At DC, the characteristic impedance equation becomes: -

$$\sqrt{\dfrac{R}{G}}$$

Because G is the inverse of resistance we can say it is the inverse of ohms so, when you analyse the above formula it becomes: -

$$\sqrt{\text{ ohms}^2} = \text{ ohms}$$

At high frequencies, the characteristic impedance equation becomes: -

$$\sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}}$$

And, if you did dimensional analysis it would be in ohms.

- Inductance is dimensionally \$M^{+1}\cdot L^{+2}\cdot T^{-2}\cdot A^{-2}\$
- Capacitance is dimensionally \$M^{-1}\cdot L^{-2}\cdot T^{+4}\cdot A^{+2}\$
- Divide inductance by capacitance: \$M^{+2}\cdot L^{+4}\cdot T^{-6}\cdot A^{-4}\$
- Take the square root: \$M^{+1}\cdot L^{+2}\cdot T^{-3}\cdot A^{-2}\$
- Dimensionally that is resistance in ohms.

[image]

Image from [IsaacPhysics.org](https://isaacphysics.org/concepts/cp_dim_analysis?stage=all).

But what about middling frequencies where all four transmission line parameters are involved. If you take into account that Inductance is multiplied by \$j\omega\$, the dimensions for \$j\omega L\$ are these: -

$$M^{+1}\cdot L^{+2}\cdot T^{-3}\cdot A^{-2}$$

Note that \$T^{-2}\$ has become \$T^{-3}\$ because of the dimensions of frequency. Now, if that is multiplied by 1/G (for example) we get ohms multiplied by \$M^{+1}\cdot L^{+2}\cdot T^{-3}\cdot A^{-2}\$. This equals: -

$$M^{+2}\cdot L^{+4}\cdot T^{-6}\cdot A^{-4}$$

And of course, by inspection this is dimensionally ohms squared. You can try the same with \$R\$ and \$j\omega C\$ but, you'll find the same. Any of the more complex "middle frequency" terms resolve dimensionally to ohms when square rooted.

Comment: Yep, basic units aren't always so basic.

Comment: I did actually do the dimensional analysis before, but think I forgot the frequencies s^-1. Thanks.

Comment: Only thing I am confused by now is that if w=so many radians per second/ the radians dont cancel out. Having J radians in a complex number doesn't make sense to me,

Comment: Is it becasue withour the per second it is considered dimensionless? Thanks.

Comment: The j part remains intact to the result but, it's still ohms but complex impedance ohms squared inside the square root.

Comment: @Andy Aka, yes but  the radians in radians/s becomes dimensionless once the /s is used to create resistance, and thus cancels in this context, right?

Comment: I believe that to be the case.